# "No bundle url present" error with react-native iOS release mode

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a native iOS app, and we're using react-native to embed a Facebook-style social feed. To run in debug mode I use the packager server and the following code:

```
NSURL *jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://X.X.X.X:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios"];

bridgeReactView = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithBundleURL: jsCodeLocation
                                        moduleProvider: nil
                                         launchOptions:nil];

rootReactView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridgeReactView
                                         moduleName:@"SocialFeed"
                                  initialProperties:@{}];
```

where X.X.X.X is my local IP address. This works fine, but I can't get it to bundle the react code into the release version. From the official docs and other Stack Overflow posts I've gathered that it was originally necessary to manually bundle the code with something like

```
react-native bundle --entry-file="index.ios.js" --bundle-output="./ios/MyApp/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest="./ios"
```

and change the jsCodeLocation definition above to

```
*jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
```

Apparently, in more recent versions of react-native, xCode will bundle the code for you  automatically if you choose the release build configuration, in which case you must change the above to

```
NSURL *jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];
```

Neither of these methods work for us - in both cases jsCodeLocation gets set to nil, and I get the "No bundle URL present" error:

```
2017-05-08 15:06:56.738 [fatal][tid:main] No bundle URL present.

Make sure you're running a packager server or have included a .jsbundle file in your application bundle.
```

Incidentally, I have tried setting the following values in my Info.plist file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</key>
```

Comment: did you add bundle react native code and images?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should do the following:

1. Run the following command:`react-native bundle --dev false --platform ios --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ./ios`
2. Add main.jsbundle and assets directory to xcode by dragging them in your project.

Note:  You only have to run step 2 the first time.

Comment: Mina thanks for this solution. I spent almost 2 days on it.

Comment: Any advice on how to force this in a CI environment?

Comment: Damn ! I've been at this for hours ! Thanks a lot mate, i don't understand why this isn't in the react-native documentation...

Comment: Although this solves my issue, this feels temporary. I've got two `main.jsbundle` files right now. Can I delete the one in my project folder? And the `assets` folder includes some node modules do I have this command every time I add new modules and manually drag the assets in my project root?

Comment: I must open Xcode and create an empty file 'main.jsbundle' first, then run the command above. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Mina M's answer was so close for me but I was getting a `File not found: index.ios.js in any of the project roots` error when calling the command. The reason behind this was because I no longer have the separate index.js files for Android and iOS - I have 1 (Which I believe it standard practice now?).

Solution - run this in the root of your React Native project (the folder with your `android`, `ios` and `node_modules` folders in):

`react-native bundle --dev false --platform ios --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ./ios`

Then you'll have to do step 2 and drag the `main.jsbundle` file and `assets` folder that have just been created in your `ios` folder, into the your project root within Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you stated that your bundle is in:

`http://X.X.X.X:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios`

But if it's a local ip or not accessible to outside network rather than your development environment, bundle url may cause such issues.

Comment: Hi Yagiz, thanks for your comment. This is the only method that works for us. We're aware that this won't work when not connected to the local network, which is why we want to bundle the react code into the app - so that we can use our app when not connected to the react-native packager server.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions above, but it didn't work until I unchecked "For install builds only" like the screenshot below.

note: make sure the metro bundler is working.

[image: uncheck "For install builds only"]