# After upgrading to React Native 0.60.5 iOS release build gives "No bundle URL present" error

Tags: ios, react-native, upgrade

I've just updated my project from React Native `0.59.9` to `0.60.5` with `react-native upgrade` and the update helper mentioned in the official blog post. Although my project is already a little "complex" because it's using some libraries etc. it seemed the update was successful.

But unfortunately my app won't work with the `Test - Release` scheme anymore. On the debug scheme it works without any problems. The release also reaches the "Build succeeded" status, but as soon the app launches it's stuck because of the "No bundle URL present" error (see also my attached Xcode screenshot).

I've tried everything I could find on the internet so far. Re-installing the NPM dependencies and Pods; removing the build folder, changing the `NSAppTransportSecurity` in the `Info.plist`, but 
it won't resolve the issue.. The deployed app via TestFlight breaks as well on startup.

### React Native info

```
System:
    OS: macOS 10.14.6
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7360U CPU @ 2.30GHz
    Memory: 430.30 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 5.3 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 10.11.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.11.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.10.1 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.4.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.11.0/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 12.4, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.4, watchOS 5.3
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 23, 26, 28, 29
      Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.0
      System Images: android-29 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 3.4 AI-183.6156.11.34.5522156
    Xcode: 10.3/10G8 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
    react-native: 0.60.5 => 0.60.5
  npmGlobalPackages:
    react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

### Steps To Reproduce

1. Update react-native from 0.59.9 to 0.60.5
2. Remove `node_modules`, `ios/Pods`, `ios/build` and `Podfile.lock`
3. Re-install `node_modules` and run `pod install`
4. Open `Project.xcworkspace`
5. Select the scheme "Project - Test" go to "Edit scheme > Run > Build Configuration" and change the scheme to "Test - Release"
6. Build the project (on device or simulator, doesn't matter)
7. "Build succeeded" and app starts
8. App is stuck on splash screen and Xcode shows the error as in the attached screenshot

### Files / Code

Currently these are my `Info.plist`, `Podfile` and `package.json`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Jobner</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>2</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Your location is required for searching jobs near you</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Your location is required for searching jobs near you</string>
  <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
  <array>
    <string>whatsapp</string>
  </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

project 'Project',
  'Prod - Debug' => :debug,
  'Acc - Debug' => :debug,
  'Test - Debug' => :debug,
  'Prod - Release' => :release,
  'Acc - Release' => :release,
  'Test - Release' => :release

target 'Project' do
  # Pods for Project
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  target 'ProjectTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  use_native_modules!
end
```

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .jsx --ext .js src/",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios --scheme \"Project - Test\" --configuration \"Test - Debug\"",
    "android": "ENVFILE=.env.dev react-native run-android --variant=devDebug --appIdSuffix=dev",
    "postinstall": "npx jetify"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/auth": "1.2.31",
    "@aws-amplify/core": "1.1.0",
    "@babel/polyfill": "7.4.4",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "1.6.1",
    "accounting": "0.4.1",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "3.0.15",
    "cross-fetch": "3.0.4",
    "dayjs": "1.8.15",
    "iban": "0.0.12",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "qs": "6.7.0",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-geocode": "0.1.2",
    "react-native": "0.60.5",
    "react-native-android-keyboard-adjust": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-bootsplash": "1.0.1",
    "react-native-config": "luggit/react-native-config#master",
    "react-native-datepicker": "1.7.2",
    "react-native-device-info": "2.3.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.3.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "0.9.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-spacer": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "2.5.6",
    "react-native-pdf": "5.1.4",
    "react-native-svg": "9.8.4",
    "react-navigation": "3.11.0",
    "react-redux": "7.1.1",
    "redux": "4.0.4",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "2.3.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "0.10.16",
    "styled-components": "4.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.5.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "7.5.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "7.5.2",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "7.2.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.5.5",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "3.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "1.10.6",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-import-resolver-babel-module": "5.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "3.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.14.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "1.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "3.7.0",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.4",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.56.0"
  },
  "xcodeSchemes": {
    "Debug": [
      "Test - Debug",
      "Acc - Debug",
      "Prod - Debug"
    ],
    "Release": [
      "Test - Release",
      "Acc - Release",
      "Prod - Release"
    ],
    "projectDirectory": "ios",
    "settings": {}
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./src/app/static/fonts/"
    ]
  }
}
```

The `AppDelegate.m` should link to the correct bundle file right? This code is in there:

```
- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}
```

(I posted this question/bug in the React Native issue tracker on Github as well.)

[image]

#### Edited:

I've found a solution in [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43854369/no-bundle-url-present-error-with-react-native-ios-release-mode).  Following these steps you can create a `main.jsbundle` and `assets` folder and add it to your project.

1. Run the following command: `react-native bundle --dev false --platform ios --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ./ios`
2. Add `main.jsbundle` and `assets` directory to Xcode by dragging them in your project.

Although this feels like a temporary solution.. I've got two `main.jsbundle` files right now. Can I delete the one in my project folder? And the `assets` folder includes some node modules do I have this command every time I add new modules and manually drag the assets in my project root?

Also when I build it via CI/CD (Bitrise) there is no `main.jsbundle` created in the root since it is ignored by default in `.gitignore`. So my TestFlight builds are still failing. How to handle this?

What exactly is happening here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

when you run in release mode its mandatory that you should have offline main.js bundle. if it not there this issue only will come. its not with 0.60.5 version it happens even in your previous version as well. so to create offline bundle you need to do step1 in the solutions that you mentioned. and from 0.60 version there is a folder called assets being created when you do this step. I'm not sure why you need to drag because if you do step 1 automatically it has to index in xcode. if that doesnt happen only you need to drag and copy items if required.

So its not a temporary solution its the solution that you need to follow to create bundle with all the changes that you have done. Its a mandatory thing in reactnative.

Note: kindly remove the both js bundles and assets folder and recreate it using

```
react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. But I must say that this did not happen in earlier version. I never had to run this command before. I see the files being automatically added indeed. But do I have to remove `*.jsbundle` from `.gitignore` now? Otherwise CI/CD builds will always fail since this file is never created right? Same goes for `ios/assets/node_modules`? And do I have to run this command every time I add new node libraries? Otherwise the assets won't be updated?

Comment: its not required to remove *.jsbundle from .gitignore. if you are cloning newly and you need to run release mode. in debug it will work and also its not required to run the command everytime when you add new node libraries. just run the command before you are creating a release build. for debug you wont face any issues because your npm server will be running. so just before generating or  running in release mode run the command. that will help you in creating the js bundle.

Comment: are you sure it didnt happened in previous versions. because i have worked with versions like 0.57.1, 0.58.3, 0.54.5 versions previously in each thing sometimes the main.jsbundle wont be updated sometimes in release mode if you dont run the command. so i excited and confused and thought of asking.

Comment: Found a solution to at least my problem. See my posted answer. Still thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the issue. Seemed like my project was missing a shell script to automatically build the bundle and assets under "Build Phases > Bundle React Native code and images". Also Xcode was crashing when I opened this section.

I opened the file `/ios/Project.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`, searched for this part:

```
/* Begin PBXShellScriptBuildPhase section */
        00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC /* Bundle React Native code and images */ = {
            isa = PBXShellScriptBuildPhase;
            buildActionMask = 2147483647;
            files = (
            );
            inputPaths = (
            );
            name = "Bundle React Native code and images";
            outputPaths = (
            );
            runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing = 0;
            shellPath = /bin/sh;
        };
```

and added the shell script, so I ended up with:

```
/* Begin PBXShellScriptBuildPhase section */
        00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC /* Bundle React Native code and images */ = {
            isa = PBXShellScriptBuildPhase;
            buildActionMask = 2147483647;
            files = (
            );
            inputPaths = (
            );
            name = "Bundle React Native code and images";
            outputPaths = (
            );
            runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing = 0;
            shellPath = /bin/sh;
            shellScript = "export NODE_BINARY=node\n../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh\n";
        };
```

Hopefully this prevents others to spend 2 days on this ;)